# Compare regex performance between golang and node.js

Tags: node.js, regex, go

I wanted to compare regex performance between using non-greedy matcher `.*?` and negative lookups e.g. `[^/]+/` and have written the following `node.js` script:

```js
const URL = "https://this-is-some-hostname-test/login?ReturnUrl=/"

const regex1 = new RegExp("^https?://.*?/(.*)");
const regex2 = new RegExp("^https?://[^/]+/(.*)$");

const iterations = 10000000;

let start = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  regex1.test(URL);
}
console.log("Time taken for non-greedy match: %s", (new Date()).getTime() - start);

start = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  regex2.test(URL);
}
console.log("Time taken for negative match: %s", (new Date()).getTime() - start);
```

This reports the following results:

```
node regexTest.js 
Time taken for non-greedy match: 386
Time taken for negative match: 305
```

Then I thought, lets check, just for the sake of it, the same in `golang`. I was expecting `golang` to be a lot faster to node.js, but to my surprise, it is actually a lot slower - 2 orders of magnitude slower in fact!

Here's my `golang` implementation:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    URL := "https://this-is-some-hostname-test/login?ReturnUrl=/"
    URLBytes := []byte(URL)

    regex1 := regexp.MustCompile("^https?://.*?/(.*)")
    regex2 := regexp.MustCompile("^https?://[^/]+/(.*)$")

    iterations := 10000000

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
        regex1.Match(URLBytes)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Time taken for non-greedy match: %s\n", time.Since(start))

    start = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
        regex2.Match(URLBytes)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Time taken for negative match: %s\n", time.Since(start))
}
```

And the results:

```
go run main.go 
Time taken for non-greedy match: 8.041351917s
Time taken for negative match: 7.905017458s
```

I tried `regex.Compile` and `regex.MatchString` in the beginning but decided to use `MustCompile` and `Match([]byte)` to eliminate any error checking and type casting. The results did not change much

Comment: "Wallclock time" (measuring the time which passed according to a clock on the wall) is not suitable for benchmarking. It can be thrown off by other things your computer is doing. Use the existing benchmarking tools for each language.

Comment: Since you never do anything with the result of the regex match, it is possible it is being compiled away. Make sure you're compiling with optimizations in Go. The strings you're matching against are quite small, you might be benchmarking regex startup time.

Comment: In node.js, everything in `regex1.test(URL);` and `regex2.test(URL);` are constants. The compiler might be optimizing it. In Go regexes cannot be constant. Try on something like input from a file.

Comment: Beside flawed benchmarking: Do yourself a favour and stop using filename arguments to go run.

Answer (score 0):

Go regexes are slow, but not *that* much slower.

There's a number of issues with your benchmarks which can account for this. The major one is to ensure the compiler isn't compiling your code away!

Because `regex1`, `regex2`, and `URL` are all constants in Node.js...

```
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  regex1.test(URL);
}
```

...can be optimized as...

```
match := regex1.test(URL);
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  match
}
```

And because nothing is ever done with the match the whole loop can be optimized away.

They are not constants in the Go benchmark.

---

To avoid these problems.

- Use non-constant input, such as from a file.
- Do something with the result, such as incrementing a counter.

I used [this list of URLs](https://dev.to/tedmasterweb/plain-text-file-of-urls-3e73) as input.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const regex1 = new RegExp("^https?://.*?/(.*)");
const regex2 = new RegExp("^https?://[^/]+/(.*)$");

const iterations = 1000;

var lines = fs.readFileSync('sample.txt').toString().split("\n");

let start = new Date();
let counter = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  for(j in lines) {
    if( regex1.test(lines[j]) ) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
}
let end = new Date();
console.log("Time taken for non-greedy match to match %d: %s ms", counter, end - start);

start = new Date();
counter = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  for(j in lines) {
    if( regex1.test(lines[j]) ) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
}
end = new Date();
console.log("Time taken for greedy match to match %d: %s ms", counter, end - start);
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    file, _ := os.Open("sample.txt")
    defer file.Close()

    var lines []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }

    regex1 := regexp.MustCompile("^https?://.*?/(.*)")
    regex2 := regexp.MustCompile("^https?://[^/]+/(.*)$")

    const iterations = 1000

    start := time.Now()
    counter := 0
    for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
      for _, line := range lines {
        if regex1.MatchString(line) {
          counter++;
        }
      }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Time taken for non-greedy to match %d: %s\n", counter, time.Since(start))

    start = time.Now()
    counter = 0
    for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
      for _, line := range lines {
        if regex2.MatchString(line) {
          counter++;
        }
      }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Time taken for negative match %d: %s\n", counter, time.Since(start))
}
```

This results in a more sensible 150ms vs 950ms. Still surprising, but within the realm of belief. Regex engines are generally are written and optimized in C, so it's less about the language and more about how optimized their regex engine is.

---

In addition, "wall clock" time is not suitable for benchmarking. Use a monotomic clock. Your Go benchmark is using a monotomic clock, while your Node is using wall clock. I haven't addressed that here.